# How can I return default value of h:selectonemenu after click button submit in jsf

Tags: jsf

I want to return null value of f:selectItem after I submitted data

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="tourCategory" value="#{placeBean.tourCateID}"
       immediate="true"
       required="true" 
       requiredMessage="tour category is required">
   <f:selectItem itemValue="${null}" itemLabel="Select..."></f:selectItem>
   <f:selectItems value="#{placeBean.listTourCategory()}" 
       var="tourCategory" 
       itemLabel="#{tourCategory.name}" 
       itemValue="#{tourCategory.tourCateId}">
   </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by clear value of `tourCateID`

This is my example that present how to set default value into `h:selectOneMenu`

XHTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Setting Default selectOneMenu</title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="coffeeSelected" value="#{coffeeBean.favCoffee3}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="${null}" 
                              itemLabel="Select...">
                </f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{coffeeBean.favCoffee3Value}" 
                               var="c"
                               itemLabel="#{c.coffeeLabel}" 
                               itemValue="#{c.coffeeValue}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" 
                             actionListener="#{coffeeBean.clear}">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" 
                        render="coffeeSelected" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

ManagedBean

```
package com.wittakarn.view;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "coffeeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class CoffeeBean implements Serializable {

    public String favCoffee3;
    public Coffee[] coffee3List;

    public String getFavCoffee3() {
        return favCoffee3;
    }

    public void setFavCoffee3(String favCoffee3) {
        this.favCoffee3 = favCoffee3;
    }

    public Coffee[] getFavCoffee3Value() {

        coffee3List = new Coffee[3];
        coffee3List[0] = new Coffee("Coffee3 - Cream Latte", "Cream Latte");
        coffee3List[1] = new Coffee("Coffee3 - Extreme Mocha", "Extreme Mocha");
        coffee3List[2] = new Coffee("Coffee3 - Buena Vista", "Buena Vista");

        return coffee3List;

    }

    public void clear(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("favCoffee3:" + favCoffee3);
        favCoffee3 = null;
    }
}
```

Domain

```
public class Coffee {

    public String coffeeLabel;
    public String coffeeValue;

    public Coffee(String coffeeLabel, String coffeeValue) {
        this.coffeeLabel = coffeeLabel;
        this.coffeeValue = coffeeValue;
    }

    public String getCoffeeLabel() {
        return coffeeLabel;
    }

    public String getCoffeeValue() {
        return coffeeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Khiêm Nguyễn why you do not interest my answer. If my answer cannot help you, you should comment. I want to know. If it not work, I will delete my post.

Comment: @wittakam so sorry, these days I am busy with my web projects.